# strtotime: Check for time

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a voucher system, where I can enter a date or a date with a time. There should be all valid formats allowed, for example this ones:

- 01.01.2016
- 01.01.2016 00:00:00

This I no problem, if I have the **start date** for  a voucher, but it is a problem if I had the **end date**. I use `strtotime` to convert the user input to a UNIX timestamp.

If you just enter the date as **end date**, it should be the end of the day used. Like this:

```
01.01.2016 -> 01.01.2016 23:59:59 -> 1451689199
```

But - and this is my problem - `strtotime` returns the same timestamp of course for `01.01.2016` and `01.01.2016 00:00:00`. And when the user enters a time, this time should be used of course.

```
01.01.2016
1451602800
-> should go to 1451689199

01.01.2016 00:00:00
1451602800
-> is correct

01.01.2016 23:59:59
1451689199
-> is correct
```

I need a possibility to check if the string - that is converted by `strtotime` - has a time explicit in it. I searched for a function for this without success, even the `DateTime` class has no method for this (`hasTime()` or something like this).

As  I said before, all date/time formats `strtotime` supports should be supported by this function also.

**This question is NOT a duplicate! I want to check if there is any time specified explicit. The question which should be the duplicate is a basic question for PHP beginners and has exactly nothing to do with this problem!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd test the length of the string before calling strtotime and add `23:59:59`:

```
$dates = array('01.01.2016','01.01.2016 23:59:59','01.01.2016 10:25:30');
foreach($dates as $date) {
    echo "date=$date\n";
    if (strlen($date) > 10) {
        echo strtotime($date),"\n";
    } else {
        echo strtotime($date . ' 23:59:59'),"\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
date=01.01.2016
1451689199
date=01.01.2016 23:59:59
1451689199
date=01.01.2016 10:25:30
1451640330
```

Comment: This is an idea ;-) I will check this :-)

Answer (score 0):

given an input of `'2015031'` or `'2015031 10:39'`, you can basicly try the first one, if it returns false try the other.

no guarantees on robustness though

```
php > var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd H:s','2015031'));
 bool(false)
php > var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd H:s','2015031 10:29'));
 object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-03-01 10:00:29.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Obviously changing the format to your needs and extracting the TS with `->getTimestamp`.

Comment: Basically, this is a good thought to validate the format. But then, I have to implement all [DateTime formats PHP knows](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)...

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your provided timestamps, the unix epoch conversions taken as input are all in GMT time. If this is the case you could try a basic check of explicitly set time by using the `gmdate` function, making an assumption that if they have values, it is a user modified timestamp.

If not, the timestamp can be modified and the 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds balance can be added to the date.

```
<?php
  $unixstamp = '1451520000'; // Thu, 31 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT
  $day = gmdate( 'Y-m-d', $unixstamp ); // 2015-12-31
  $hour = (int)gmdate( 'H', $unixstamp); // 0
  $minute = (int)gmdate( 'i', $unixstamp ); // 0 

  //check if hours or minutes have been set explicitly 
 if( $hour > 0 || $minute > 0 ){
   //User Modified Time
   echo gmdate("c",$unixstamp);

 } else {
   //here add the 23 hours and 59 minutes on and return as date object
   echo gmdate("c", strtotime('+23 hours + 59 minutes + 59 seconds', $unixstamp));  

   //here add the 23 hours and 59 minutes on and return as unix epoch timestamp
   $endofday = gmdate("U", strtotime('+23 hours + 59 minutes + 59 seconds', $unixstamp));   
 }
?>
```

Timezones are definitely a consideration but the above code will check a GMT unix timestamp for explicitly set time.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, that I want to know if a time have been set. What if is someone set the time explicit to 00:00:00? ;-) The default should not be 00:00:00 but 23:59:59, to say it with other words.

Comment: Right so you want the time changed on the user end? What method does the user interface have for entering the end date? I would look to your front end for feedback on wether time was explicitly set.

Comment: I just have a text field for the date/time and try to parse the entered value with `strtotime`. Of course, I can integrate a date chooser...

Answer (score 0):

By default, all timestamps include time, even if it's not set, it will be 00:00:00.

So in this case, you could do something like this:

```
<?php 

$notime = 1420070400;
$withtime = 1420110000;


$time = date("H:i:s", $withtime);

if($time == "00:00:00") {
    echo "time not set";
} else {
    echo "time set";
}
```

?>

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, that I want to know if a time have been set. The default should not be 00:00:00 but 23:59:59, to say it with other words.

Comment: In that case you could just have a boolean when submitting the form if the time was set by the user or not. If not then replace 00:00:00 with 23:59:59